# SubSingleBenchmarker error while Partitioning Optaplanner

Tags: search, partition, optaplanner, concurrentmodification

I am trying to run benchmarking with partitioning in it. Partitioning works well with a smaller problem but when I try to run it over a greater number of planning entities I get the following error.
I tried deleting the `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` tag from some of my getters but I still get the same problem.

Any ideas where this might be coming from?

```
The subSingleBenchmarkRunner (Problem_0_First Fit Decreasing DDU_1) failed.
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1239)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1048)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at com.Problem.utils.ProblemPartitioner.splitWorkingSolution(ProblemPartitioner.java:60)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.partitionedsearch.DefaultPartitionedSearchPhase.solve(DefaultPartitionedSearchPhase.java:94)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:88)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:191)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:106)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Since the exception comes from `ProblemPartitioner`, which is your custom implementation, I do not see how I could help, or how this could be related to OptaPlanner.

That said, I will take a guess that maybe you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` in a concurrent environment?

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.subList()` doesn't do a copy of the list. Any changes to the sub list affect the original list.

So when your ProblemPartitioner splits a List into 4 distinct sublists, it should use `new ArrayList(originalList.subList())` so it has a copy of sublist.